# Hasty close on a question about aussie-rules/rugby?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I realized that [a question regarding similarities/differences between aussie rules football and rugby](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/337/what-is-the-difference-between-australian-rules-football-and-rugby) got shot down, on the grounds of being "unclear what the question is about".

Considering that these two disciplines are pretty closely related, for an outsider the differences and similarities might not be obvious. I think it's worth reconsidering the question, as I see it definitely salvageable. I voted for reopen there, and figured it might be useful to have a discussion here on meta.

Comment: Community? Time to speak up! :)

Comment: has been reopened

Comment: I am glad that the question got salvaged. On another note, I am worried that the Sports.SE community is not maturing as we had hoped it would..

Answer (score 2):

It's a very poor [LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=What+is+the+difference+between+australian+rules+football+and+rugby%3F) question. It's on par with asking "What's the difference between a cabbage and a watermelon" on a cooking Q&A site. The current answers are fine, but necessarily not very informative, since it's really unanswerable as it stands.

The only way to salvage it would be too ask "Are Rugby and AFL closely related sports" or something similar. The simple answer "No" then at least addresses the question.

I re-voted to close.

Comment: There were six weeks between this meta question being asked and the main question being reopened, and not one user had mentioned to keep it closed.

Comment: "Are Rugby and AFL closely related sports?" says "Are cabbages and watermelons closely related produce?" Is it best in quality? Not quite, but it can be improved...even if one has to ask similarities between the sports and how the application is different, or something. That's for everyone (the community) to decide.

Comment: "Are Rugby and AFL closely related sports?" No, because AFL is not a sport: it's a *league* (the clue's in the name). The *sport* is Australian Rules Football (which is not a close relative of rugby: they have a similarly shaped ball and that's about it).

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is legit and should be reopen.

Question about differences between sports rules was asked here - [Differences between NBA and European/FIBA/Olympic basketball rules](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/differences-between-nba-and-european-fiba-olympic-basketball-rules/1036#1036).

It seems little bit weird that the question was closed without any comment since it was improved by @minimatt and @posdef.

And in case someone thinks the question is still isn't good he is more than welcome to improve it or comment on it.

We are suppose to welcome and teach new users and not to eliminate their questions without any response.

Comment: This question was closed in February, comment being "low quality." Although both rules questions aren't exactly best in quality, I think good information can be drawn by seeing the differences between each sport.